# Display driver on Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, graphics-card, windows-server-2008-r2

I install Windows Server 2008 on virtualbox and I have a problem with display driver. As default windows settings I have standard VGA display driver which is not support resolution of my monitor on fullscreen mode. I have Geforce GT220 on my machine and when I try install driver on virtual there is problem because system does not detect geforce graphic card.
How to install geforce display driver on virtual machine with windows server 2008 r2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt install your actual display card driver, you should install "VirtualBox Guest Additions", i am on mobile and hard to formatting a reply,  please refer to this link fot details instruction http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solves my problem. Do you have any additional tips for improve working with virtual machine?

Comment: I think snapshot feature is quite useful http://www.howtogeek.com/150258/how-to-save-time-by-using-snapshots-in-virtualbox/